# Should you disavow for every property in Search Console?

Tags: disavow-links

When disavowing links you do so by individual property in Search Console. Most sites will have multiple properties (www / non www / https etc.)

When disavowing, should I upload the same disavow file for every property?

Comment: You can disavow an entire domain if you believe the links occur on multiple URLS.

Comment: Thanks Simon but my question is do you disavow for each Search Console property, not whether you can disavow entire websites.

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad.

Comment: See:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92821/do-you-need-to-disavow-on-https-ssl-after-performing-a-disavow-on-http if you previously submitted a disavow pre SSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should upload a disavow file only on which you can see/download the backlinks reports.

So first go the [external links tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/external-links), select your proprieties, and if you see the backlinks report then upload disavow file on that property only.

No need to upload same disavow file in other properties like www, non-www, http. I personally upload only to `https://www.example.com` because I have SSL certificate and www subdomain.